# "Layers" and "Layer Preview" tabs not working

Tags: geoserver, java

I've just setup a new geoserver and installed some extensions.
Now I'm unable to navigate to the "Layer" and "Layer preview" tabs. They just don't load.

> 2022-03-28 15:14:16,357 ERROR [status.OSHISystemInfoCollector] - null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> 2022-03-28 15:14:16,357 ERROR [status.OSHISystemInfoCollector] - null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> 2022-03-28 15:14:16,357 ERROR [status.OSHISystemInfoCollector] - null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> 2022-03-28 15:14:16,357 ERROR [status.OSHISystemInfoCollector] - null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> 2022-03-28 15:14:29,123 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: {0}
> 2022-03-28 15:14:44,156 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: {0}
> 2022-03-28 15:15:29,206 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: {0}

I'm running Geoserver 2-20-2. Ubuntu version 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa).

Comment: Remove all extensions that you added and try if GeoServer is OK. If it is, add extensions one by one. Maybe you can find the one that makes the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the sqlserver extension was breaking the Geoserver. Specifically the file mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar